# How to get Properties from a Neo4j Database in Server Plugin after Commit?

Tags: java, plugins, neo4j, server, graph-databases

I have to implement a Neo4j Server Plugin that reacts to changes to the Database and get's information about those changes. I need to get all the Data that has been added, changed and deleted in a transaction. I use a `TransactionEventHandler` registed to the database. For performance reasons i have to use the `afterCommit` callback that is called after the changes to the database have been made. This way the transaction will not be held back by the plugin.

Now inside this callback i do something similiar to this:

```
public void afterCommit(TransactionData data, Void arg1) {
    for(Node n:data.createdNodes()) {
        String firstkey = n.getPropertyKeys().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

But the `getPropertyKeys` throws an Exception because the transaction has already been commited. I don't understand why this is a problem, i don't want to change anything to the transaction, i just want properties the node has that has been changed. Is there some way to work around this? What is the reason for the Exception?

The Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This transaction has already been completed.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.assertTransactionOpen(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:376)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.acquireStatement(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:261)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.acquireStatement(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.instance(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$8.statement(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:785)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getPropertyKeys(NodeProxy.java:358)
    at de.example.neo4jVersionControl.ChangeEventListener.afterCommit(ChangeEventListener.java:41)
```

Comment: Have a look at this, I think it could save you some work: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/tx-api

Comment: Thx, but this event handler takes place "Before a transaction commits". I need it after the commit. Also the Graphaware framework under windows only works in the zip download of Neo4j which is the enterprise edition, but to develop i use my own PC with the community edition which is a exe download. That is noted on the Git Repo of Graphaware. Therefore using Graphaware would be difficult for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `afterCommit` the transaction has already been committed (hence the name). To access properties from a node you need a transactional context - remember that every operations (even readonly) require this.

The recommended way for implementations of `TransactionEventHandler`s is to rely on `TransactionData` only. `TransactionData.assignedNodeProperties()` will return the properties of the newly created nodes as well.

Comment: When trying to get the start and end node of a relationship via eiter `r.getNodes()` or `r.getStartNode()` I run into the same problem. Do you know how to work around this one?

Comment: I came across the same issue regarding getting information about getting more info about a relationship in afterCommit without being in a transaction. Any help?

Comment: since it's in `afterCommit` you theoretically can spawn there a new transaction reading the relationship (and its properties). Be very careful with that, since afterCommit might be called recursively in this case.